# Complete PublishSubject after all events processed

Tags: multithreading, rx-java

I have a service that uploads files to a server. I have it setup as a `PublishSubject` to which I pass events defining the files to upload. The `PublishSubject` sequentially processes these events on a background thread (using a single thread executor). 
However, the problem is that I need to unsubscribe the `PublishSubject` once all files are uploaded. The way to determine if all files are uploaded is whether the `PublishSubject` received another event while the last event was being uploaded. If the upload finishes successfully and no new event is received, the stream should terminate.
I tried the following:

```
publishSubject
    .timeout(file -> uploadFile(file))
    .doOnError(throwable -> if(isTimeout(throwable)) cleanup())
    .subscribe(response -> logResult(response))
```

The timeout variant will timeout if no new event is passed to the `PublishSubject` by the time the `uploadFile` observable returns, which is the expected behavior. Except, when an event IS passed before `uploadFile` observable completes, it unsubscribes from that `Observable`.

So what I need is a way to queue up the events and for each event to processed in order but if the queue is empty by the time the processing (uploading in this case finishes), the stream should terminate. How can that be accomplished?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the stream should terminate"? You haven't defined what a stream is in your example, so I presume you have some kind of infrastructure that you need to manage.

Comment: The subscription to the `PublishSubject` should receive a terminal event, either an `onComplete` or an `onError`. So for example, the `doOnError` in the above code snippet should be called.

Comment: If there's an alternate way to tell if there's nothing in the queue, then that would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The happy path for a single request that succeeds could be satisfied by

```
publishSubject
    .flatMap(file -> uploadFile(file))
    .subscribe(response -> logResult(response),
               throwable -> if(isTimeout(throwable)) cleanup(),
               () -> logResult("completed"));
```

where, I presume, `uploadFile(file)` returns an `Observable<Response>`. the `.flatMap()` operator will take the request that it receives and pass it as a parameter to `uploadFile(file)`. When the observable returned by `uploadFile()` completes, it will either first log a response or not, and then log a complete.

No enhancements are required for an error, as the second lambda in `subscribe()` takes care of that.

We have two cases to worry about: 1) additional requests from upstream, and 2) a timeout during the upload. In the second case, we can use an operator on the observable returned by `uploadFile()`, the `timeout()` operator will do nicely.

```
publishSubject
    .flatMap(file -> uploadFile(file))
    .timeout( 5, SECONDS )
    .subscribe(response -> logResult(response),
               throwable -> if(isTimeout(throwable)) cleanup(),
               () -> logResult("completed"));
```

In the first case, we may not want to have more than one upload operational at a time. `.flatMap()` takes an additional operator, which is the maximum concurrency supported. Your solution is now:

```
publishSubject
    .flatMap(file -> uploadFile(file), MAXIMUM_SIMULTANEOUS_UPLOADS)
    .timeout( 5, SECONDS )
    .subscribe(response -> logResult(response),
               throwable -> if(isTimeout(throwable)) cleanup(),
               () -> logResult("completed"));
```

So, what's left to do? I believe your original solution was almost right, but what you were missing is where the subscriptions where. The subscriptions are as follows:

1. `publishSubject` is subscribed to the requesting service. When the requestor has no more files to upload, then that subscription will complete.
2. The `.flatMap()` operator creates a subscription internally to its observable.
3. The `.flatMap()` operator will create a subscription for each `uploadFile()` observable that it creates.
4. Finally, the `.subscribe()` step is the final subscriber to the whole chain.

So, how is `publishSubject` unsubscribed from its requestor? You need to add a step before the code to save the subscription, and a termination step in your observable chain to unsubscribe:

```
Subscription subscription = requestor.subscribe(publishSubject);
publishSubject
    .flatMap(file -> uploadFile(file), MAXIMUM_SIMULTANEOUS_UPLOADS)
    .doAfterTerminate( () -> subscription.unsubscribe() )
    .subscribe(response -> logResult(response),
               throwable -> if(isTimeout(throwable)) cleanup(),
               () -> logResult("completed"));
```

Edit: removed `timeout()` operator as it is handled by `uploadFile()`.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What happens in the case where file1 in pushed at time `t`, file2 at `t+1` but the upload of file1 takes 10 seconds. Wouldn't the stream timeout at 5 seconds result in neither file being uploaded? Secondly, with MAXIMUM_SIMULTANEOUS_UPLOADS, what's handling backpressure?

Comment: You have to select your timeout appropriate to the file upload time. I assumed that `uploadFile()` was not handling upload timeouts, but apparently, I was wrong; we can remove it. For the second part, the `publishSubject` is handling back pressure; it will need to have whatever buffering is required.